# how can I integrate hedara hashgraph and flutter?

Tags: flutter, cross-platform, hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

I want to create Mobile Dapp . I want to build the front end through dart Flutter . How can I integrate it wiith the Hedara hashgraph?

I couldnt find any resource for this online.

I could have gone forward with Ethereum or any other blockchain , but i have to do it with hedara hashgraph for a hackathon.